# Android system overlay with canvas or GLSurfaceView is extremely slow

Tags: android, canvas, transparency, overlay, glsurfaceview

I want to implement something non-standard in Android.

I've created transparent system overlay (`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`) on top of everything with `GLSurfaceView` (then I changed it to canvas) and I'm trying to draw something on it.

The problem is that Android becomes very slow when trying to blend my transparent layer with other things under it. I know that this operation will be slow, but it's **very** slow. I tested on more or less power devices.

Few facts and observations:

- My overlay view is fullscreen
- System becomes slow even if I draw nothing to overlay
- My Acer Iconia tab (10") runs it much much slower than my Droid X (more pixels to blend? Or new rendering pipeline?)
- If I use a static `ImageView` with a transparent PNG than Android blends it
  without problems. Why? Does Android check what to blend every frame?
- Enabling hardware acceleration on the tablet has no effect

My question: Is it possible to optimize it somehow? I set background of my View to null but it had no effect.

Will Android 4.0 be as slow as 3.2?

It's especially slow when it blends a system overlay over the home screen. Why?

Please do not tell me that I'm writing the wrong things and using API for things other than their designated purposes, I'm already aware of that.

Comment: Something tells me that Android 4.0 ICS is no better. The problem isn't the OVERLAY, or the GLSurfaceView, but the combination. Especially since you require transparency, memory use would be rather high. Adding HW acceleration would only increase memory use. Now try that on a Galaxy Nexus 1280 x 720, your simply pushing too many pixels.